# Allow IP addresses in Network Policy Flutter Android

Tags: android, flutter

After the recent changes Landed in version: 1.23 now Insecure HTTP connections are disabled by default on iOS and Android.

After adding this snippet in Manifest.xml

```
<application ...>
 ...
<meta-data android:name="io.flutter.network-policy"
         android:resource="@xml/network_security_config"/>
</application>
```

This is my network_security_config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
<domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">15.535.243.8</domain>
</domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

After this, if I run my Android app I still get an exception.

```
 [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(210)] Dart Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument (domain): Invalid domain name: "15.535.243.8", stack trace: #0      new _DomainNetworkPolicy (dart:io/network_policy.dart:85:7)
 E/flutter (12820): #1      _constructDomainPolicies (dart:io/network_policy.dart:181:22)
 E/flutter (12820): #2      _EmbedderConfig._setDomainPolicies (dart:io/embedder_config.dart:44:23)
 E/flutter (12820): 
 F/flutter (12820): [FATAL:flutter/lib/io/dart_io.cc(38)] Check failed: !LogIfError(set_domain_network_policy_result). 
 E/flutter (12820): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(210)] Dart Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument (domain): Invalid domain name: "15.535.243.8", stack trace: #0      new _DomainNetworkPolicy (dart:io/network_policy.dart:85:7)
 E/flutter (12820): #1      _constructDomainPolicies (dart:io/network_policy.dart:181:22)
 E/flutter (12820): #2      _EmbedderConfig._setDomainPolicies  (dart:io/embedder_config.dart:44:23)
 E/flutter (12820): 
 F/flutter (12820): [FATAL:flutter/lib/io/dart_io.cc(38)] Check failed: !LogIfError(set_domain_network_policy_result). 
 F/OIC_SRM_DOXM(20621): UpdatePersistentStorage failed!
 F/OIC_SRM_DOXM(28806): UpdatePersistentStorage failed!
```

Comment: did you find any solution for this problem?

Comment: hi did you find a solution to this problem Juan?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `http://15.535.243.8` ? http scheme is needed to validate your IP Address

Comment: In your `AndroidManifest.xml` add the attribute `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in the `<application></application>` tag

Comment: AndroidManifest.xml in debug?  or main? D:

Comment: In `app/src/main` bro

Answer (score 0):

The exception you're seeing is because of **"Invalid Domain name"**, regardless of it's secure or not (http or https).

An IP won't work here, you need to **register a domain name** and link it to your server, then you may enter the domain name instead of the IP.

If you're working only on a **local network** and you need this only for **development purposes**, then you can edit your `hosts` file and **supply a domain name** for the provided IP.

For example,

```
 15.535.243.8    example.com
```

and your network_security_config.xml will be something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
  <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">example.com</domain>
  </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the below code in AndroidManifest.xml file for network security config.

```
<application ...>
...
<meta-data android:name="io.flutter.network-policy"
         android:resource="@xml/network_security_config"/>
</application>
```

But it didn't fix the issue for me.

Then like it's done in native android projects, I added the below code in AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<application ...
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
    ...
</application>
```

And this fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Remove network config xml file if you added **

```
<application ...>
 ...
<meta-data android:name="io.flutter.network-policy"
         android:resource="@xml/network_security_config"/>
</application>
```

Add the below code in your debug manifest file

> Goto -> Project -> android -> src -> debug -> AndroidManifest.xml

add following code

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

<application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:node="merge" />
```

Then your manifest will look like this

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.project">
    <!-- Flutter needs it to communicate with the running application
         to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:node="merge" />

</manifest>
```

> Note: This will work only on debug build